# Filling an array from a list

Tags: python, numpy

I am new at python and I have a problem trying to filled an array with the data of a list

For example my list looks like:

```
Item TIMESTEP
0
STEPS
Id mol Sp x y z
1 1 0.25 0.63 0.58
2 1 0.85 0.96 0.10
3 2 0.36 0.45 0.89
4 3 0.45 0.16 0.22
5 3 0.85 0.65 0.77

Item TIMESTEP
10
STEPS
Id mol Sp x y z
1 1 0.85 0.33 0.68
2 1 0.65 0.26 0.20
3 2 0.56 0.35 0.79
4 3 0.75 0.36 0.12
5 3 0.65 0.75 0.87
```

... and continues like that ofr 1000
What I would like to do is to have an array containing just the values of X, Z, Y next to each other, but just the first one and the next one, because I need to use just the coordinates to get relative values, so comparing each time step with the direct previous one.
Until now I have this, but the array is not giving any result... Could you tell me what is wrong or how to correct it?

```
numofmol = 600
B = np.zeros((numofmol,6)) #array filled with ceros with 6 columns and 2688 lines
A = list() # empty list A

c=0


with open('./square/output/Sq.lammpstrj') as inf:
    for line in inf:
        parts = line.split() # split line into parts 
        #print parts
        if len(parts) > 1 :
            if parts[1] == 'TIMESTEP' :
                c +=1
            #print c
        if len(parts) == 5 and numofmol >= parts[0] > 0  :
            if c % 2 == 0:
                    B[parts[0],0] = parts[2]
                    B[parts[0],1] = parts[3]
                    B[parts[0],2] = parts[4]
            else:
                    B[parts[0],3] = parts[2]
                    B[parts[0],4] = parts[3]
                    B[parts[0],5] = parts[4]

            print B
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: it would be nice to see an example output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit hard to get, what do you really want, but you can try something like this:

```
data, c = {}, 0
with open('./square/output/Sq.lammpstrj') as inf:
    for line in inf:
        parts = line.split()
        if len(parts) > 1 and parts[1] == 'TIMESTEP':
            c += 1
        if len(parts) == 5:
            if c % 2 == 1:
                data[parts[0]] = parts[2:]
            else:
                data[parts[0]] += parts[2:]

B = np.array(data.values())
```

Comment: len(Id mol Sp x y z) == 6 :)

Comment: Didn't get it, why deleting your comments and -1?

Comment: Although now the order is correct (timestep 1 next to timestep 2) is just taking random values of the original list. not making an array with all the values

Comment: do you have example input so i can test it?

Comment: Thank you!! got it!! :),
if len(parts) == 5:
if c % 2 == 0:
B[int(parts[0])-1,0] = float(parts[2])
B[int(parts[0])-1,1] = float(parts[3])
B[int(parts[0])-1,2] = float(parts[4])
B[int(parts[0])-1,3] = float(parts[1])
else:
B[int(parts[0])-1,4] = float(parts[2])
B[int(parts[0])-1,5] = float(parts[3])
B[int(parts[0])-1,6] = float(parts[4])
B[int(parts[0])-1,7] = float(parts[1])

Comment: sorry, I just read this... but you are right! I can accept this:)